# Service does not start after updating; how to do dependencies between components

Tags: wix, wix3.7

we have an installer which does install a windows service and some files. Sometimes when we update an installation with a new installation (by simply installing the new package; a minor upgrade, product version changes, product id does not change), the service cannot start. This is because some files are missing in the installation folder which are needed by the service during service start up.

Currently we only have only `<Feature />` and there is only one `<ComponentGroup />`. The `<ComponentGroup />` itself contains the service and contains some other components, which has files. It looks like this (empty attributes are placeholders and are actually filled):

```
<Component Id="" Guid="" Directory="">
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
</Component>
<Component Id="" Guid="" Directory="">
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
</Component>
<Component Id="" Guid="" Directory="">
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
</Component>
<Component Id="" Guid="" Directory="">
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <File Source="" Id="" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no">
        <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" ResetPeriodInDays="5" />
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

The bad thing is that the service depends on some other components.

How can you specify those dependencies? Or do I need to put all the files in the component which contains the `<ServiceInstall />`?

Thanks,
Johannes

Comment: I already forgot, that I posted a question about this here :) The problem was something related with our build process and had nothing to do with WIX itself. Anyway thanks for you reply. By the way, how can I mark this question as answered or something?

Comment: I thought that might be the case (since the question is so old). I expanded my comment and posted it as an answer, if you want to mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is caused by something else. A good plan to help discover the real problem is to run `msiexec MyApp.msi /log install.log` and inspect the resulting log file. That log can prove whether the files are installed first and could uncover another issue.

During the InstallExecuteSequence when the actual installation is performed, Windows Installer installs components through a sequence of actions. The action that lays down files on disk is called [InstallFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the action that starts services is called [StartServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Unless you tell it to do otherwise, WiX schedules the StartServices action after the InstallFiles action, so all the files should be present on disk before the service is started.